# How to push an object to another Vue component

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Element UI library with Vuejs framework (configured using Vue CLI).

I currently have a nested input form that is taking information and pushing it to an object array inside of a parent component, but I'm having a lot of trouble sharing this information to a child component.

I believe using props is the correct approach, but I'm not sure I'm declaring the props correctly. I also have the parent / child set up with vue-router.

Form in parent component...

```
<div>
      <el-dialog title="Create a new space to huddle" :visible.sync="createHuddleVisible" width="1000px" height="200%">
        <el-form :huddle="huddle" :index="index">
          <el-form-item label="Huddle Headline" :label-width="formLabelWidth">
            <el-input v-model="newHuddle" autocomplete="off" placeholder="What should we call this meeting?"></el-input>
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Goal" :label-width="formLabelWidth" :autosize="{ minRows: 1, maxRows: 2 }">
            <el-input type="textarea" v-model="newGoal" placeholder="Use this text box to quickly establish the goal of this huddle.">
            </el-input>
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Body" :label-width="formLabelWidth">
            <el-input style="white-space: pre-line;" type="textarea" :autosize="{ minRows: 10, maxRows: 15 }" v-model="newBody"></el-input>
          </el-form-item>
          </el-form>
        <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
          <el-button @click="createHuddleVisible = false">Cancel</el-button>
          <el-button type="primary" @click="addHuddle">Confirm</el-button>
        </span>
      </el-dialog>
    </div>
```

The 'addHuddle' method successfully takes all strings and creates new objects.

I would like to use the data captured here and displayed in a child component.

For now, I've just been trying to print one of the object values onto a card as a test with no luck. Blank card.

```
<template>
    <el-card class="huddle-box-card" shadow="always">
      {{ huddle[0].goal }}
   </el-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'HuddleSpaceOne',
    props: {
      huddle: {
        type: Object
      },
      index: {
        type: Number
      },
     }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What error you got here?

Comment: @HarshPatel I'm not getting an error or warning. It's just not populating to the other component. I tried adding the props both in the <script> of the vue file (child), and also tried adding the props in the router.

Comment: Show me your router.js file